# Outlook Rest api, how to store the photo?

Tags: vba, rest, outlook, outlook-restapi

i think this is a pretty simple question, sorry.

I have with

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts('AAMkAGE1M2IyNGNm===')/photo/$value
Content-Type: image/jpg
```

read the photo.

but now i don't know how to save this photo value as a jpg file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, here is my own answer:

```
photo.Write web_HTTP.ResponseBody
```

use ResponseBody (an array) instead of ResponseText!

Answer (score 0):

Is the question too stupid?

I am trying to write the binary stream from HTTP.responsetext to the disk as a binary stream with ADODB.
But the created file cannot be read.

```
Dim bytA() As Byte
bytA = web_HTTP.ResponseText
Set photo = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    photo.Type = 1 
    photo.Open
    photo.Position = 0
    photo.Write bytA
    photo.SetEOS
    photo.Position = 0
    photo.SaveToFile "Test" & ".jpg", adSaveCreateOverWrite
    photo.Close
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions or tips.

Need help!